# How do I analyze a double moderator?

Tags: regression, anova, interaction, predictor

My set up is as follows:

I have a predictor x, that predicts the levels of y. Along the way, there are two moderator variables that may affect the strength of the x-y relationship.

I am at a loss at how to go about trying to find if there is a moderating effect, and how strong, since there are two moderators instead of just one.

Any and all help will be very appreciated. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with plotting the data followed by multiple linear regression.

If you are using `R`, you can make a matrix plot by simply plotting all of your variables of interest.  For example if your data is stored in columns 1, 5, 6, and 8 then you would use `plot(data_frame_name[,c(1,5:6,8)])` or `subset()` the `data_frame_name` and `plot()` the entire `subset`.  Ocular inspection methods are usually all that is required to test for reasonable correlation between the variables of interest.

You could then test this with the function `lm(`$Y$`~`$x_1+x_2+x_3$`)`. If you wish to test the variables with interactions, then use `lm(`$Y$`~`$x_1$`*`$x_2$`*`$x_3$`)`.  After storing the linear model as a variable, you can then view the summary of your model(s), which includes an ANOVA and the significance of each factor (and interaction, if that is included).